# iphone App publishing Issue

Tags: iphone

We had submitted/distributed our application using wild card bundle identifier.

For Example :- 48NPCXXX.in.co.xyz.*

Now we are publishing an update version of the application with push notification feature.

How we can publish the update version with wild card appID.

Or we have to publish as new application.But in this case how old users
get notified of the updates.

We followed the instruction given in below link but it does not work for us.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/qa1680.html

Look forward for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

The steps in that document are what you need to follow.  Whoever has the current version of the app installed will be notified through the AppStore that there is a new version available and they can update it just like they would normally.  You just have to follow the steps to make sure you don't have the wildcard appID and that you have all your notification certificates correctly registered.

Answer (score 0):

It seems QA1680 has been removed.  [This looks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH18-SW1) like it might be its successor.